# How to get audio frequencies from mems microphone in PC oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, fft, mems

I'm fairly new to electronics/signal processing and I'm stuck on trying to obtain frequencies from an [Adafruit SPW2430](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2716) MEMS microphone. I tried plugging the microphone to a [Hantek 6022BE](https://www.amazon.ca/Hantek-Digital-Oszilloskop-Storage-Oscilloscope/dp/B0728HBNDV/ref=sr_1_50?crid=1EFN6KGJLTXSV&keywords=oscilloscope&qid=1648659130&sprefix=oscilloscop%2Caps%2C147&sr=8-50) PC oscilloscope, powering the microphone with a [3.3V power supply board](https://www.amazon.ca/Power-Supply-Module-Solderless-Breadboard/dp/B00BXWV2F6) but two problems arise. First is I can't save the FFT measurements given by the oscilloscope software, only the voltage measurements, next is that when I connect the microphone output and ground to the oscilloscope probe, whilst powering it with the power supply, the voltage meter in the PC oscilloscope doesn't show any measurements. I would like to know if I need to amplify the signal from the microphone or if I am missing something, also how I could get the FFT measurements from the voltage.

Comment: Check you're getting a DC voltage on the DC output pin to verify the module is getting powered. Check the oscilloscope is working by plugging the leads into the on-board 1V PkPk sinewave test pin. Check you have the correct voltage scaling (V/Div) on the graph so you can see  the waveform (100mV peak to peak)  Check all the grounds are connected.

Comment: *First is I can't save the FFT measurements given by the oscilloscope software, only the voltage measurements,* - then save the voltages and then feed them to MATLAB or similar to calculate FFT.

Comment: Ok I think I was just connecting the microphone wrong,(everything else seems to be working as well) I adjusted the vertical and horizontal scale on the oscilloscope and am getting the voltage output of the MEMS microphone, but how could I save it in real time?